# Difference between re.sub and re.findall

Tags: python, regex

I have strings which look like "Billboard Bill SpA". I want to have a regular expression that removes SpA, but only if there is a capitalised word before it. The regular expression I use is "[A-Z][a-z]*\s(SpA)". If I use re.sub both the SpA and the capitalised word before it get removed, which is expected.

```
re.sub("[A-Z][a-z]*\s(SpA)", "", "Billboard Bill SpA")
'Billboard '
```

However, if I use re.findall I get the functionality I need:

```
re.findall("[A-Z][a-z]*\s(SpA)", "Billboard Bill SpA")
['SpA']
```

I know I can write a pre expression with "?<=" which doesn't consume the pre text, but that works only for fixed length expressions. Anybody know what I can do to only remove "SpA" with re.sub, or make it work like re.findall?

**To be more clear**
I want a regular expression to remove Spa, but only if there is a capitalized word before:

```
re.sub(regular_expresssion, "", "Billboard Bill SpA") -> Billboard Bill
re.sub(regular_expresssion, "", "to SpA") -> to SpA
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question exactly is! Could you explain a little using simpler English (using words like _this is input_ and _this is desired output_)?

Comment: I added more info to the text of the question which makes it more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `re.sub` is replacing the entire match, not just the group `(SpA)`. That's why it's also removing `Bill`. `findall` on the other hand is giving you the group.

In `re.sub` you can specify to include the part of the match that you don't want to delete.

```
re.sub("([A-Z][a-z]*\s)SpA", "\\1", "Billboard Bill SpA")
'Billboard Bill '
```

If you want to delete the space as well, move `\s` outside of the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Perform the substitution using groups.

```
>>> re.sub("([A-Z][a-z]*\s)(SpA)", "\\1", "Billboard Bill SpA")
'Billboard Bill '
```